# Octopus Deploy tentacles and 2 Nuget packages?

Tags: sql-server, deployment, nuget, octopus-deploy

I'm learning about the environments and machines of Octopus. I have a Web project that is packaged into a Nuget package and deployed to Azure Websites, and I also have a DB project that is packaged into a separate Nuget package to SQL Azure. When Octo picks them up and deploys, is it better to have two separate machines have tentacles for each in the same environment, or should they be on one machine (in the case that the website deployment passes and the DB doesn't)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're deploying to Azure, it doesn't really matter - 1 tentacle is enough for ALL environments (regardless of project type). We do this all the time for our Azure projects. You can think of the tentacle being a PowerShell script runner against Azure; nothing *really* happens on the actual server itself.

You can have multiple Octopus "environments" using the same tentacle (especially for Azure) - as you can reuse the same tentacle. This will allow you to use different scopes for your variables to apply the appropriate values per each logical environment, all the while targeting just one server which does runs scripts against Azure.